# QgisPy: Как выполнить метод в основном потоке плагина к QGIS по сигналу из другого потока?

Tags: python, многопоточность, плагин, qgis

Добрый день!
Задача такая: написать плагин к QGIS, который дает возможность другим приложениям обратиться к QGIS и выполнить некие действия (например, приблизить карту к определенному объекту)
Для этого решили при запуске поднимать HttpServer. Запускать сервер приходится в отдельном потоке, иначе QGIS не загружается. Эта часть работает. 
Но для выполнения задачи необходимо иметь возможность взаимодействовать с iface. Из потока сервера это ожидаемо приводит к ошибке, поэтому мне необходимо каким-то образом дать понять  потоку плагина, что нужно выполнить некий метод.

Я пыталась сделать это через event и цикл с ожиданием, но это опять приводит к зависанию самого qgis

Пример кода ниже

class GoToListenerPlugin:

```
def __init__(self, face):
    self.face = face

def initGui(self):

    e = threading.Event()
    self.event = e
    self.server = MyServer(('localhost', 8085), Handler, e)
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever)
    self.thread.daemon = True

    self.thread.start()

    while not e.isSet():
        event_is_set = e.wait(5)
        if event_is_set:
            self.uiAction()
        else:
            pass
```